# range(strtotime("00:00"), strtotime("23:59"), 30*60) does not work properly after upgrade laravel to 7. Is it php problem?

Tags: php, laravel

After upgrade Laravel 7 from 6 I have got an error.

Array used to have total 48 items but now 50 items.
Is it php error? or laravel error?

I tested on laravel 5 it gives total 48 items.

```
$times = [];

$range= range(strtotime("00:00"), strtotime("23:59"), 30*60);
foreach($range as $time){
    $times[] = date("H:i",$time);        
}

return $times;  



array:50 [▼
  0 => "00:00"
  1 => "00:30"
  2 => "01:00"
  3 => "01:30"
  4 => "02:00"
  5 => "02:30"
  6 => "02:00"
  7 => "02:30"
  8 => "03:00"
  9 => "03:30"
  10 => "04:00"
  11 => "04:30"
  12 => "05:00"
  13 => "05:30"
  14 => "06:00"
  15 => "06:30"
  16 => "07:00"
  17 => "07:30"
  18 => "08:00"
  19 => "08:30"
  20 => "09:00"
  21 => "09:30"
  22 => "10:00"
  23 => "10:30"
  24 => "11:00"
  25 => "11:30"
  26 => "12:00"
  27 => "12:30"
  28 => "13:00"
  29 => "13:30"
  30 => "14:00"
  31 => "14:30"
  32 => "15:00"
  33 => "15:30"
  34 => "16:00"
  35 => "16:30"
  36 => "17:00"
  37 => "17:30"
  38 => "18:00"
  39 => "18:30"
  40 => "19:00"
  41 => "19:30"
  42 => "20:00"
  43 => "20:30"
  44 => "21:00"
  45 => "21:30"
  46 => "22:00"
  47 => "22:30"
  48 => "23:00"
  49 => "23:30"
]
```

6 => "02:00" and 7 => "02:30" are duplicated.
Any advice please?
Thanks

Comment: It works fine: https://3v4l.org/JWKH2 it must be something else than the code you provided

Comment: Isn't your problem related to a Daylight Saving date ?

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz Yes you are right! Day light saving finished today. Now it is working fine as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why. It is because of day light saving. @JoffreySchmitz commented. Thanks.